# Match a textual pattern in Java

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, pattern-matching

I have two text files say input.txt and pattern.txt.

Let's say the pattern.txt files look somewhat like this.

```
*             *
**           **
 **         **
**           **
**           **
**           **
     *****
```

Now, I have to find all the occurrences of the above pattern in the input.txt file as per some defined threshold. 
Can someone give me some leads how can I do this in Java?

I know of an Open-CV and template matching libraries but they help to process images and not the textual patterns. 
Can someone give initial inputs, please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the pattern.txt to a matrix with 0 for spaces and 1 for *. Call it patterntMat

Do the same for input.txt. Call it inputMat

Now use template matching with the patternenMat as the template and inputmat as the image.

Comment: Hi Amitay, 

Is there any library or helper links you think I can work with to convert a text file to matrix of 1s and 0s ? 
Thanks.

Comment: I think that you can do it yourself no need for any library.

Comment: Hi AMitay, Yes I did that on my own. Can you answer my next part of the question here, please? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45892193/how-to-find-a-match-in-the-result-mat-opencv-object-in-java